# How get information about post from facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api

Suppose to have an post_id and I must get if post exists or not. 
The code is :

```
https://graph.facebook.com/1485990275062935/
```

I obtain this error:

```
{
   "error": {
      "message": "An access token is required to request this resource.",
      "type": "OAuthException",
      "code": 104,
      "fbtrace_id": "G4De0dxJHFM"
   }
}
```

Anyone can help me to pur access token in link?

Comment: `https://graph.facebook.com/1485990275062935?access_token=...`

Comment: FYI, that will _not_ tell you whether a post _exists_ or not; the only conclusion you can draw from the API response is whether or not your app can _read_ this post using the access token and the permissions it includes. If it can not read it, the response will be the same as if that object did not exist at all (“Unsupported GET request”)